# How do I Transfer Instantiate put inside OnCollisionEnter() after created on another function OnCollisionExit() in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm creating my first game "Endless Runner" and my problem is in the code, I don’t need to destroy the new object, I need to transfer them to the old place.

```
public class GenerateEnv1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject []EnvTile;

    float tileZ = 29.31f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        if(col.gameObject.tag =="ground"){
            GameObject o = Instantiate (EnvTile[Random.Range(0,4)], new Vector3(0f,0f,tileZ), Quaternion.EulerAngles(0,0,0));
            tileZ += 2.96f;
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionExit (Collision col) {
        if(col.gameObject.tag =="ground"){
            Destroy (col.gameObject,3); // this's i need to replace that in the new object 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean "I need to replace that in the new object."? What is going where?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you should declare GameObject o as a global variable and then you can access it on your OnCollosionExit method

Comment: @Draco18s when in run the game I generate the new Ground and when the character collision in the first groud and generated them, and destroy the old Ground "collision with them", I need when the character collision with the ground I need to transfer the new Ground in the forward the character

Comment: @Ido Ben Shalom when i declare the GameObject as a public the console Come out to me Error" Unexpected  symbol 'public' "

Answer (score 1):

Since instantiating and destroying a tile is more costly, every time you leave a tile OnCollisionExit will fire and you will move that tile right after the next tile and so on and so forth, also instantiating two tiles onStart is enough since we're reusing them

```
public class GenerateEnv1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] EnvTile;

    float tileZ = 29.31f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(EnvTile[Random.Range(0, 4)], new Vector3(0f, 0f, tileZ), Quaternion.EulerAngles(0, 0, 0));
        Instantiate(EnvTile[Random.Range(0, 4)], new Vector3(0f, 0f, tileZ * 2), Quaternion.EulerAngles(0, 0, 0));
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            col.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(col.gameObject.transform.position.x , col.gameObject.transform.position.y, col.gameObject.transform.position.z + (tileZ * 2));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , but why use vector2 in OnCollisionExit ?

Comment: To move the old tile in front of the new tile thus making it the new tile

Comment: yep, but the old tile comes above the new instantiating tile :( !

Comment: you're right, check out the edit for the correct placement

Comment: i checked the placement and true :/ , now when instantiating  the new tile ? why instantiating two tiles onStart ? Could this be the problem?

Comment: What's the tile's length?

Comment: I put 12 tile's

Comment: the tile Z 'spaceing' between us = 2.96

Comment: Can you further explain on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is called Object Pooling. 
There's a tiny bit too little detail to provide a full code as an answer, but in general it works like that: Instantiate all the objects you'll need when the game loads, this is farily expensive and is best done at front.

Than, everything you do is do some juggling with gameObject.SetActive(true/false).

Generic implementation will contain a list of gameobjects (pool), you deactivate (instead of destroing) an object on OnCollisionExit, than you take new object from the pool (pick one that is not active), and activate it (and place it).

It is not clear however how the colliders are placed, obviously collision will not be triggered by an object that is not yet active on scene.

Is your script meant to go on the player?